# How to print `auth` from the Firebase Security Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there a way to print/return the payload of `auth` inside the Security Rules, when making a call to a Firebase Realtime database?

I'm struggling to get a rule to work and it seems like it's because `auth.uid` doesn't contain the value I expect it to have. Is there a way to print the value it has?

---

**Update:**

In the security rules the first line below converts to `true` while the second line converts to `false`. I expect `auth.uid` to be `22`, so would also expect the second line to convert to `true`.

```
root.child('projects').child($project_uuid).child('person').child('22').exists()  // is true
root.child('projects').child($project_uuid).child('person').child(auth.uid).exists()  // is false
```

After exploring the sent data under Network > ws (see image below), I still expect `auth.uid` to be `22` and therefore the second line to convert to `true`. Any reason why this might not be the case?

[image]

---

**Minimal case:**

Database content:

```
projects: {
  "abcd": {
    person: {
      22: {
        permissions: {
          read: true
        }
      }
    },
    data: {
      allKindOfData: "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

Security Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "projects": {
      "$project_uuid": {
        "person": {
          ".read": "true"
        },
        ".read": "root.child('projects').child($project_uuid).child('person').child('22').exists()
               && root.child('projects').child($project_uuid).child('person').child(auth.uid).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit of a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you edit your question to show the minimal code, minimal-but-complete rules, and minimal existing data with which any of us can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks, I've added a minimal case to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Printing/logging in the security rules is not possible AFAIK. If you want to check the value of `auth.uid` that is sent to Firebase you can log it in your front end: If the user is signed-in, its `uid` will be sent together with the queries to the Firebase back-end services, e.g. the RTDB.

On the other hand you can use the "Rules Playground" module to debug your rules.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Renaud, I think I've found a way to see the value and have added an update to my post.